# Web forms - .Net Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working for a customer to update his web application C# (for future migration to more recent technologies).

There is are separate configurations, and one of them we need to have the line numbers shown in the stack trace when an exception occurs. Build & Advanced Build Settings have been adapted (Pdb-Only) and then deployed (to Azure App Service).

Now when an error occurs, the exception is triggered, but it still doesn't show the line numbers.

[Advance Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUe4C.png)

Debug information has been updated to:
[Advance Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yj7I.png)

Also, when closing Visual Studio (Community/Professional and Enterprise) 2022, after saving the change, and re-opening the project the Debug information has been set back to **none**.

**Example of stacktrace:**
Stacktrace:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
    at MyApp.SiteMaster.master_Page_PreLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
    includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

**Should be (in bold):**
Stacktrace:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an 
    instance of an object.
    at MyApp.SiteMaster.master_Page_PreLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    **in C:\code\MyApp\project\MyApp\Site.Master.cs:line 64**
    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
    includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: I would try setting the debugging information box to full. It not going to hurt the site, and you STILL going to publish the site as build mode = release, and thus really no performance issues exist. I was under the impression that line numbers show EVEN without the ..pdb file. However, why not set the .pdf file build  = full.  And you noted "migration", are you pulling out code into separate class objects and projects? If yes,, then include the .pdb for each such external class. So, set debugging infomration = full, and I hard pressed to think why doing so is a bad idea? (its' ok).

Comment: It is possbile that you not using a "application". For an application, then I assume you publish, and that means the site is pre-compiled before deploying. As such, the publish wizard WILL include the .pdb file, and does so even when you compile as release mode.

Comment: Hi Albert,
Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this didn't help either. I've put for each (project/class) the same configuration settings to Full. Saving all projects closing VS and the reopening reverts back to none (so Full is gone again).
Next I tried to set it again, then build, and then publish. PDB is not taken with.
Though, the PDB files do exist in the Bin folder.
I also ask another developer to do the same on his VS installation. The result is exactly the same.

Comment: After further investigation it seems that changing to Pdb-Only or Full doesn't even create the PDB file. Are other any other places that might override this? Also, I've checked the Package/publish Web tab, and 'exclude generated debug files' is unchecked.

Comment: If settings don't save, then all bets are off for ANY valid testing. Obviosity that lack of saving issue has to be addressed first else this is a waste of time. When you note/talk about settings not being saved, are you talking about multiple projects that exist in one project, or are you simply stating that for this one project, those settings don't work and don't save? This sounds like some permissions issues when you copied/un-zipped the project. I would ALWAYS launch VS as administrator, and see if that helps.   So, MASSIVE waste of time to try options when you state options don't save

Comment: Hi Albert,
Indeed. I've noticed in the meantime the same. I'm checking it as when saving the change, it does update the csproj file. But Visual Studio isn't loading it. I've tried with a different version of VS2022 (as I'm on the latest stable release), also 2019. Same result. I'll keep on looking. Will post the solution when I've found it as well.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, please read [ask], especially the section labeled "Write a title that summarizes the problem" -- the current title is merely a repeat of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it seemed that the configuration profile was somewhat 'corrupted'. Any new change was discarded even after a save.
The solution has multiple projects (web, class, ...) and it was applicable on any project. Though the default Debug/Release profiles weren't a problem.

To resolve it, I had to do some refactoring:

1. Removing the faulty profile from the solution
2. executing `Get-Project -All | Foreach { $_.ConfigurationManager.DeleteConfigurationRow("PROFILENAME") }` to clean any leftovers
3. Creating a new profile (**Note:** *don't use the same name as the deleted one or it won't work either*)
4. Set the configuration on the solution (Build)
5. Update the build profiles for each project
6. Rename/re-create the App.XXXX.config / Web.XXXX.config files in each project where applicable.
7. Update the publishing profiles to use the new configuration profile.

Once all this is done, I could make changes to the build profile and build with the generation of the PDB.
Better to be safe than sorry, I did this in a separate branch!!! Just to be on the safe side.